# 引数の連想配列のインデックスと要素を表示する関数をphpで作成する方法

Tags: php

foreach,function関数を使って引数の連想配列のインデックスと要素を表示する関数のプログラミングコードを教えてほしいです。<?php 以降の文が全く分かりません。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: スタックオーバーフローではプログラムの作成依頼的な質問は回答が集まりづらい傾向があります。動かなくても構わないのでご自身が試したテストコードや試行錯誤した履歴を載せるととより回答が集まりやすいでしょう。

Comment: [あわせて読みたい](https://teratail.com/questions/274106)

Answer (score 1):

質問文コメントのリンク先QAサイトで解決済みかもしれませんが、コード例は下記のようになります。

```
<?php
// 連想配列を引数にとる関数
function myfunc($array) {
    // 連想配列のインデックスと要素を列挙するforeach文
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key: $value\n";
    }
}

$array = array("hoge" => "foo", "fuga" => "bar", "piyo" => "buzz");
myfunc($array)
?>
```